# Are plastic dryer vent fittings (not hose) allowed with gas dryers?

Tags: dryer, vent

I'm trying to use a ovalized to 90 degree connector for my metal flexible hose connector in my dryer
and the only one I can find is plastic at the big box store that is made for specifically for dryer vents.

I know not to use plastic flexible hose. [The fitting](https://www.lowes.com/pd/IMPERIAL-6-25-in-x-4-in-Plastic-Oval-Duct-Elbow/1000772574) will not be concealed, but there seems to be conflicting information regarding the use of plastic but cannot find an official recommendation.

Not looking for specific product endorsements just general guidance on the use of PVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes, unless otherwise specified.

I wasn't able to find much information about the specific one you linked, but if you go to other home improvement websites, they tend to list more information, as well PDF spec sheets. Home Depot for example, has a bunch of these made of plastic, that all say they are OK for use with gas or electric dryers.

If there is a manufacturer phone number on the box or tag for this specific unit, I would just give them a call and ask.